# how do I exclude some data from RDD in scala and spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala and spark.Now I have a RDD and the data like this:

```
[
 (key1, compactbuffer(item1, item2, item3)),
 (key2, compactbuffer(item3, item4))
 .....
]
```

the another RDD is:

`[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6]`// it's ordered.

Then I want to get the Result like this:

```
[
   (key1, compactbuffer(item4, item5, item6), 
   (key2, compactbuffer(item1, item2, item5, item6)
]
```

how do I achieve it?

Comment: Is the second RDD huge?

Comment: Did you group the data to get it into that format?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto it's very large

Comment: @DavidGriffin yes, the first RDD is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two `RDDs` were named `grouped` and `master`, this should do it:

```
grouped.cartesian(master).filter(t => {
  var found = false;
  t._1._2.foreach(r => {if (r._2 == t._2) found = true});
  !found
}).map(t => (t._1._1, t._2)).groupBy(x => x._1)
```

Comment: Sorry, had some code in there (e.g:.`map(r => r.getString(0))`) that I was using to pull the data out of an `RDD` created from a `DataFrame`, but may or may not be relevant to you.

Comment: The second RDD is very large. cartesian may be not a good way.

Comment: At least it keeps it all as RDD, so you can distribute it. But a `cartesian` is unfortunately what you need to do.